# Set height of the row in Primefaces panelGrid

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I'm trying to implement a page using PrimeFaces to get this.

[image]

I have this code.

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%" >                
    <p:row id="first-row">
        <p:column>
            <div id="top">
                <ui:include src="..." />
            </div>
        </p:column>
    </p:row>    
    <p:row id="second-row">
        <p:column>
            <div id="bottom">
                <ui:include src="..." />
            </div>
        </p:column>             
    </p:row>                
</p:panelGrid>
```

and CSS is

```
tr#first-row {
    height: 60%;
}

tr#second-row {
    height: 40%;
}
```

I don't want to set the height to `<td>` or `<div> inside <td>` because I like it to be flexible using percentage,
60% first row and 40% second row of the 100% height table.

Problem is table doesn't take full available space of the browser.
Currently, the table is empty so it doesn't even take half of the browser.

IE view source code look like this:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to use a panelGrid? If not, I recommend using the layoutUnit tag. Have a look at the showcase here (especially the full layout): http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/element.xhtml